# Google Cloud Datalab - insufficient permissions for project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I am using Google AppEngine to run an application. I am now trying to setup the Google Cloud Datalab. I have the Compute Engine enabled. When I try to deploy, I get the following error in the log:

```
...
Jan 26 21:48:20 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript: Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
Jan 26 21:48:22 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript: If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while.../#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...-#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.
Jan 26 21:48:22 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript: WARNING: If this is your first deployment, please try again.
Jan 26 21:48:22 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
Jan 26 21:48:22 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript:   Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
Jan 26 21:48:22 datalab-deploy-main-20160126-21-46-14 startupscript:   Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~prjectId'). App Engine service account has insufficient permissions for project. Developer or owner required.
```

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Is the `app_id='s~prjectId'` mentioned in the error message matching your app's actual ID (from the developer's console)? If not you need to update your app's `.yaml` file(s) accordingly.

Comment: yes! I have changed the text here not to disclose the real app id (as it is not important...)